# Браузер не слушает класы

Tags: html, css, gulp, scss

[image: Браузер не видит класс который введен в scss]

Браузер не видит класс который введен в html и не слушает стили через css

Comment: css не показали, в ту область которую Вы обвели, попадают инлайн-стили

Comment: значит css файл не подключен

Comment: ```.line_animation {
    stroke-dashoffset: 600;
    stroke-dasharray: 600;
    animation: animedash 2s infinite 6s;
}

@keyframes animedash {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}```

Comment: стили правильно подключены в файл?

Comment: да.
блин даже к обычному спану не слушает

Comment: задаю спану стили, и опять в инспекторе только элемент

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy А про то добавлены ли стили уже спрашивали?

Comment: @bonusrk - 2 комментарий от Valera Kvip.

Автор, покажите - как вы подключили файл со стилями.